# How do I play this part in 'Alouette'?

Tags: piano, technique, legato

[image]

Is the slur telling me that I simply have to play it legato on all the notes on the treble clef and also when i transition from the C note to the G note (on the bass clef). Or is it telling me that I have to play all the notes on both staves in legato?

Comment: This is pretty much the same as your last question. The book style seems to be to not use legers but to drop to the bass clef.

Comment: You perhaps need to try a different book! This is exactly the same 'problem' as in the previous question. Let's face it, most things you are going to play such as this will have to be played legato. How else should it be played?  Unless there's staccato marks, it is played legato - doesn't make much sense otherwise.   That apart, you are still on the nursery slopes, I guess. Try using ears a lot more, they're great guides.

Comment: In this, and the OP's other similar question, presumably the music editor is trying to arrange the music so you never have to change your hand position. That idea about how to start to learn keyboard playing is a left-over from 200-year-old instruction books - but hey, following a system that is now completely out of date is easier than actually *thinking* about what you are trying to teach your students! I'm inclined to agree that the best use for these two arrangements would be lighting a fire with the paper they are printed on, not learning to play them!

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the correct answer. The bow is only for the upper voice.
In order to acchieve this, you have to play the upper g from the last chord in the left hand a little bit shorter.

Since I am not allowed to comment yet, I need to add something to Tim's answer:
Pop-piano is mostly played legato. But, note that even Chopin's standard way of playing was non-legato (In every place he wanted a legato he wrote a bow - and he wrote lots of bows). And there is a good reason for that: Using both playing-styles heavily increases the quality of the performance.
Therefore: If there is a legato-bow play legato, **if there is no bow play non-legato**, if there are staccato marks play staccato.

Nevertheless, the book you are using seems not to care about legato. In my opinion, the bow must end at the c.
This score would be a much better one:

https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a8/36/81/a8368164256dc777fbcba2aca5c812ca.gif

Answer (score 1):

The slur is indicating that the melody travels into the lower stave.  I'd be inclined to ignore the printed fingering and play the entire melody with the RH.
This isn't a terribly good bit of arranging.  The priority seems to be maintaining hand position rather than serving the music.  OK in elementary teaching material I suppose.   Don't treat it with TOO much respect!